# Compare current time with given time

Tags: c, time, compare, time.h

So...I'm trying to compare the current date with a date initialized by me. I have this code but it always enter into the if comparation, even though the dates are different. Any help, please?

```
   int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm  data;

  data.tm_year=2014-1900;
  data.tm_mon=12-1;
  data.tm_mday=27;
  data.tm_hour=17;
  data.tm_min=4;
  data.tm_sec=0;

  time ( &rawtime );

  if(mktime(&data) == time(&rawtime))

   {
    printf("Same date\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yours might, mine doesn't (nothing printed). Compiled with VS as given (plus #includes). Is this your *exact* program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison is wrong it should be

```
if (mktime(&data) == rawtime)
```

Or just

```
if (mktime(&data) == time(NULL))
```

also, initiazlize **all** the fields of `struct tm data;` or

```
memset(&data, 0, sizeof data);
```

Comment: `time()` returns the same value that it writes to the pointer argument (if supplied). "The time function returns the number of seconds elapsed since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), according to the system clock. The return value is stored in the location given by timer."

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, that's why I propose the second way of doing it, if the OP doesn't need to store the return value of `time()`, then the second method is preferred, at least I prefer it.

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: Both methods work, try this `time_t rawtime; struct tm *data; time(&rawtime); data = localtime(&rawtime); if (mktime(data) == rawtime) printf("Same data\n");`.